# Remove array elements that are present in another array

Tags: arrays, ruby, array-difference

There is a list of words and list of banned words. I want to go through the word list and redact all the banned words. This is what I ended up doing (notice the `catched` boolean):

```ruby
puts "Give input text:"
text = gets.chomp
puts "Give redacted word:"
redacted = gets.chomp

words = text.split(" ")
redacted = redacted.split(" ")
catched = false

words.each do |word|
  redacted.each do |redacted_word|
    if word == redacted_word
        catched = true
        print "REDACTED "
        break
    end
  end
    if catched == true
        catched = false
    else
        print word + " "
    end
end
```

Is there any proper/efficient way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`.reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject) to exclude all banned words that are present in the `redacted` array:

```ruby
words.reject {|w| redacted.include? w}
```

[**Demo**](http://repl.it/mbX/1)

If you want to get the list of banned words that are present in the `words` array, you can use [`.select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select):

```ruby
words.select {|w| redacted.include? w}
```

[**Demo**](http://repl.it/mbX/4)

Comment: btw.. to side track. anyway to remove only the first occurrence?

Answer (score 20):

It also can works.

```
words - redacted
```

`+`, `-`, `&`, these methods are very simple and useful.

```
irb(main):016:0> words = ["a", "b", "a", "c"]
=> ["a", "b", "a", "c"]
irb(main):017:0> redacted = ["a", "b"]
=> ["a", "b"]
irb(main):018:0> words - redacted
=> ["c"]
irb(main):019:0> words + redacted
=> ["a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b"]
irb(main):020:0> words & redacted
=> ["a", "b"]
```

Comment: The only problem is that this isn't very flexible. If you needed to make it case-insensitive for example, you'd have to switch to one of the other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit more 'elegant'. Whether it's more or less efficient than your solution, I don't know.

```
puts "Give input text:"
original_text = gets.chomp
puts "Give redacted word:"
redacted = gets.chomp

redacted_words = redacted.split

print(
  redacted_words.inject(original_text) do |text, redacted_word|
    text.gsub(/\b#{redacted_word}\b/, 'REDACTED')
  end
)
```

So what's going on here?

- I'm using `String#split` without an argument, because [`' '` is the default](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-split), anyway.
- With [`Array#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject), the following block (staring at `do` and ending at `end` is executed for each element in the array—in this case, our list of forbidden words.

  - In each round, the second argument to the block will be the respective element from the array
  - The first argument to the block will be the block's return value from the previous round. For the first round, the argument to the inject function (in our case `original_text`) will be used.
  - The block's return value from the last round will be used as return value of the inject function.
- In the block, I replace all occurrences of the currently handled redacted word in the text.

  - [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-gsub) performs a **g**lobal **sub**stitution
  - As the pattern to be substituted, I use a regexp literal (`/.../`). Except, it's not really a literal as I'm performing a string substitution (`#{...}`) on it to get the currently handled redacted word into it.
  - In the regexp, I'm surrounding the word to be redacted with [`\b` word boundary matchers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). They match the boundary between alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters (or vice verca), without matching any of the characters themselves. (They match the zero-lenght 'position' between the characters.) If a string starts or ends with alphanumeric characters, `\b` will also match the start or end of the string, respectively, so that we can use it to match whole words.
- The result of `inject` (which is the result of the last execution of the block, i.e., the text when all the substitutions have taken place) is passed as an argument to `print`, which will output the now redacted text.

**Note** that, other than your solution, mine will not consider punctuation as parts of adjacent words.

Also **note** that my solution will be vulnerable to regex injection.

#### Example 1:

```
Give input text:
A fnord is a fnord.
Give redacted word:
ford fnord foo
```

My output:

```
A REDACTED is a REDACTED.
```

Your output:

```
A REDACTED is a fnord.
```

#### Example 2:

```
Give input text:
A fnord is a fnord.
Give redacted word:
fnord.
```

My output:

```
A REDACTEDis a fnord.
```

(Note how the `.` was interpreted to match any character.)

Your output:

```
A fnord is a REDACTED.
```